# Log4net in Crystal reports on Windows Azure with IIS 32

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, crystal-reports, log4net

My Tools: Visual Studio 2010, Crystal Reports 13, MVC3 APP, Windows Azure

When I publish my MVC app in Windows Azure, i get the error: `Could not load file or assembly 'log4net' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

My SO is 64 bits and server run in 32. I try change my app to deploy on ANY CPU and 32 BITS but does not effect. The assembly that i call is:

```
<add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
```

If i remove the assemble and compile,  local works fine. But if publish I get the error. Looking in GAC i found two log4net, one in AMD64 and other in 32 Bits. Probably removing the reference on web.config  then works  local because the .net framework finds in GAC every register that is refered, but then Azure obviously not work.

How publish my 64 bits app in Windows Azure with log4net right to generate the crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this erro is necessary check 3 points:

1° How i said in my question, processor (AMD64 or x86) is one of fonts of the erro. Some articles say about change the deploy mode from ANY to x86. This not fix this error, and generate others bugs depending of situation. Dont do this.

2° This [LINK](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_bi/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333533353330333833353334%7D.do) show how change the log4net for work. In some cases this can fix the problem.

3° If your processor is correct with version of log4net  and the bug persists, install in your server the Crystal Reports CR again, in my case works, perhaps the instalation fix some other bugs in bin folder. In my case, i need to install Azure Cloud app.